# Maven failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5

Tags: maven

As I am rather new to Maven I tried to create a small empty project similar to [Maven in 5 Minutes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html). Though every time I run

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

it I get this error:

```
[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.546 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-10T14:33:31+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/109M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/rpod/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/rpod/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:93)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:266)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:220)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:89)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

I looked up several pages though they either state that my firewall is blocking it, which I checked but it is currently inactive, or my proxy settings are wrong, which also can't be since I am not using one.

I also tried to open up those links manually and they work just fine which, I also tried to run it on a different machine and it worked out of the box.

Also my Maven version is (via the `mvn --version` command):

```
Java version: 1.8.0_66-internal, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.2.0-30-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Lastly my current `settings.xml` setup:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                           https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
        <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
        <usePluginRegistry>false</usePluginRegistry>
        <offline>false</offline>
</settings>
```

Even after looking through the entire log from executing it with the -X parameter I still don't see the issue.

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Maybe paste your command line

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the plugin+version precisely:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Also, try to check that the settings.xml you shared is the one being used. The file can live either at:

- The Maven install: `$M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml`
- A user’s install: `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`

The user's install would override the global one.

Comment: Thanks for your input, the settings.xml is in the user install. Sadly specifying the plugin+version didn't help either.

Comment: What do you see if you try to download it like so? `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get -DrepoUrl=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 -Dartifact=org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4`

Comment: Pretty much the same: `[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:pom:2.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]`

Comment: The serial number of the certificate is the same for me. I also tried to disable the SSL check, though it also didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out my JDK version was corrupted for some reason. After completely purging every directory and reinstalling both JDK and Maven it works again.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem after switching my JAVA_HOME and PATH to jdk1.7.0_80 .

Switching it back to jdk1.8.0_172 solved it for me.